# hook_uc_add_to_cart in template

Tags: 7, hooks, ubercart

I'm using Drupal 7 + Ubercart 3 and am trying to run a piece of code just before the user adds a product in cart. [hook_uc_add_to_cart](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_add_to_cart) seems to be the right function to use for it. So I'm trying to utilize it using the following syntax in `template.php` file of my template

```
function tbw_uc_add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data){die('here: ' . $qty);}
```

where `tbw` is my template name. I've flushed all caches but the above code does not work as it doesn't `die()` when I add a product to cart. I suspect the problem is that this hook can't be implemented in a template because the documentation only talks about using it inside a module, i.e., `Some modules need to be able to hook into the process of adding items to a cart...`.
Can anybody please shed some light on why it is not working and guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect the problem is that this hook can't be implemented in a template

Correct :)

Only `hook_theme()`, preprocess hooks, and alter hooks can be implemented in template.php. For any others, including this one, you'll need to [write a custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

Comment: Just what I didn't want to be told :D Drupal keeps boasting off the steepness of its learning curve on me :( thank you for your help (another weekend to drupal) :)